# Point to folder in <script> tag

Tags: javascript

When you are loading JavaScript files via the <script> tag, you can only do it one-by-one, ie `<script src="myFile.js">` or so I'm assuming. Is there a way to load an entire directory of .js files like `src="dir/*"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No - you cannot, by definition, (see [RFC 1738](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html)) incorporate a wildcard into a URL.

If you have server-side scripting access you could embed a block of code which inserts a script tag for every file read from a directory or you could concatenate the scripts on-the-fly (concatenation is generally preferable as it requires less overhead to download a single concatenated file).

Most efficient solution: concatenate the relevant script files and link to that file from one `<script>` declaration.

---

> [H]ow exactly would I do that
>   on-the-fly?

Here's an example of how you might do that with a PHP file named `all-js.php` in the same directory with all your scripts:

```
<?php
    $output = '';
    $dir = dirname(__FILE__);
    $files = scandir( $dir );
    if ( $files )
    {
        foreach ( $files as $file )
        {
            if ( '.js' == substr( $file, -3, 3 ) )
                $output .= "/* file: $file */\n\n" . file_get_contents($file) . "\n\n";
        }
    }
    echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: mmm.. I know what "concatenate" means, but how exactly would I do that on-the-fly?

Comment: (Added PHP example)

Comment: Wow thanks for the help! I'm just getting into php now, so I only know the basics. It works great!